# Bash command to (re)move duplicate files [eg photos]

Tags: bash

If I have a directory with a bunch of photos and some of them are duplicates [in everything except name], is there a way I can get a list of uniques and move them to another dir?

Eg

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 md5sum
```

that will give me a list of "md5 filename"

Now I just want to look at uniques based on that...
eg pipe that to `sort -u`.

After that I want to mv all of those files somewhere else, but I can worry about that later...

Comment: Apparently there is a similar question on su: http://superuser.com/questions/386199/how-to-remove-duplicated-files-in-a-directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [fdupes](http://linux.die.net/man/1/fdupes):

`fdupes -r .`

to get a list of duplicates. The move should be possible with some command chaining.

`fdupes -r -f .`

Shows you only the duplicated files. So if you have an image twice. You'll get one entry instead of both duplicated paths.

To move you could do:

```
for file in $(fdupes -r -f . | grep -v '^$')
do
  mv "$file" duplicated-files/
done
```

But be aware of name clashes..

Answer (score 1):

From there:

```
sort | uniq -w 32
```

Will compare only the first 32 characters, which I believe should be the md5sum itself.

Comment: Perfect. To get a list of files so far, I have `find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 md5sum | sort | uniq -w 32 | cut -d' ' -f2-`
...
Just need to mv them, now.

Or I can not grow a long beard and just use fdupes, it seems.